# power bi dax - previous quarter value?

Tags: time, powerbi, dax

I have a simple table with data in the following format:

```
category | score | date
cat1     |     3 | 31/3/2019
cat2     |     9 | 31/3/2019   Q1 data
cat3     |     7 | 31/3/2019
...
cat1     |     6 | 30/6/2019
cat2     |     4 | 30/6/2019   Q2 data etc.
cat3     |     1 | 30/6/2019
```

Basically, I have many rows for quarterly data (scores for different categories) where the date column references the actual quarter. I have a chart where I'm showing the values from the latest quarter (most recent data), but I need a column to give me previous quarter's score. I found out about PREVIOUSQUARTER, which looked like an easy trick, but it returns blanks.

```
prevQtr = CALCULATE(SUM(data[score]), PREVIOUSQUARTER(data[date]))
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I tried creating a date table, with continuous dates between the first and the last date of my column, it didn't help. No other time intelligence function seems to return anything, so I guess it's something generic. I tried the documentation, but it doesn't mention any limitation. What I'm looking for is:

```
category | score | date      | prevQtr
cat1     |     3 | 31/3/2019 | 
cat2     |     9 | 31/3/2019 |
cat3     |     7 | 31/3/2019 |
...
cat1     |     6 | 30/6/2019 | 3
cat2     |     4 | 30/6/2019 | 9
cat3     |     1 | 30/6/2019 | 7
```

Thanks

Screenshots:

[image: the chart]
[image: the data]
[image: the date table]
[image: the relationship]

Comment: Can you update to show 1. the relationships in your model and 2. the layout of the chart where your [prevQtr] code failed (select the chart and screengrab the whole PBI window)? That measure definition with a proper date dimension should work just fine.

Comment: screenshots added! all date columns are date type formatted as dd/mm/yyyy.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend just using a measure to achieve this, BUT.. your measure:

```
prevQtr = CALCULATE(SUM(data[score]), PREVIOUSQUARTER(data[date]))
```

Needs to reference your date table:

```
prevQtr = CALCULATE(SUM(data[score]), PREVIOUSQUARTER('dateTable'[date]))
```

This modification should do it.

Comment: Note: the asker is adding this as a column. That refactor is insufficient to get PrevQtr working in a column.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, three things here.

1. You need to reference your date dimension date column for the built in time intelligence functions. (Note, this also implies you should only use date fields from the date dimension. Hide 'data'[date] in your fact so you aren't tempted to use it.)
2. Since you're adding this as a calculated column, you're going to have to do some extra context manipulation.
3. Since there is no context being contributed by the date dimension here (you're only in row context of the fact table), you can't use a built-in time intelligence function effectively here.

So! My suggestion is to define your PrevQtr as a measure, rather than a column, in which case it will work with the small refactoring below:

```
PrevQtr =
CALCULATE (
  SUM ( 'Data'[Score] ),
  PREVIOUSQUARTER ( 'dateTable'[Date] ) // just referencing the date table here
)
```

If you must create a calculated column for this, and your data all follows the pattern in your sample of having values on the last day of the quarter, then I think this is the best bet for it:

```
PrevQtrColumn =
VAR CurrentRowDate = 'Data'[Date]
VAR PriorQuarterEnd = EOMONTH ( CurrentRowDate, -3 )
RETURN
  CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'Data'[Score] ),
    ALLEXCEPT ( 'Data', 'Data'[Category] ),
    'Data'[Date] = PriorQuarterEnd
  )
```

The big gotcha there is covered by the `ALLEXCEPT`. `CALCULATE` converts all row context to filter context, so your 'Data'[Score] values become filter context. `ALLEXCEPT` clears that, preserving only the [Category].